# Xamarin, Android: "Missing AdActivity with android:config..." C#!

Tags: c#, android

I work on an android app in Visual Studio.
When I implement a simple banner, the banner in this app says:
"Missing AdActivity with android:configChanges in AndroidManifest.xml."

I looked this issue up and many people had this problem but it always was in Android Studio. Can you help me out? I think it might have something to do with my manifest - which looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.TalkAboutTv2.TalkAboutTv2" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:label="Talk About Tv"></application>
  <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
</manifest>
```

THanks :)

Comment: have you added `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>`?

Comment: added where? thanks!

Comment: As a child of your `<application>` tag

Comment: and also your `<activity>` should go inside `<application>`

Comment: that totally fixed it THANK YOU A LOT :))

Comment: Great :) I will post it as an answer so that the others might make use of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make some changes to your code:
1) `<activity>` must be a child of the `<application>`
2) Add this

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

to the `<application>` too.

This should result in the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.TalkAboutTv2.TalkAboutTv2" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:label="Talk About Tv">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```